# Null Pointer Exception in If condition

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
     Product p = dao.checkProduct(pnumber);
     ExpensiveProduct ep = dao.checkexpensiveProduct(pnumber);
     if ((p.getNumber() == null)&&(ep.getNumber()==null) ){ // java.lang.NullPointerException 
     //do something

     }else{
    //do something

      }
```

Why this statement giving  `java.lang.NullPointerException`
Do I have any other way to check this?

Comment: Make sure `p` and `ep` are non-null before calling `getNumber()` on them.

Comment: Full error? + More of the code...

Answer (score 3):

The only non-trivial possibility where this code can throw NPE is `pnumber` being `Integer` where `checkProduct()` or `checkexpensiveProduct()` expects `int` (or similar).

Other trivial reasons are `dao` or `p` being `null` (easy to check).

Comment: i need to check that nulls and get true on that statement can i && those 2?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
if ((p != null) && (p.getNumber() == null) && (ep != null) && (ep.getNumber()==null) ){
```

Comment: this always false i need to do else part also any idea to do that?

Comment: If it's always false, I think you have your answer.  Fix p and ep.

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException`s (NPEs) occur when you call a method or access a property of a `null` object.

To check for `null`s, you could print the values of your variables before you try to use them, or step through your program with a debugger and check what the variables' values are when you reach the line where the exception happens.

EDIT:
Regarding your comment

> i need to check p.getNumber() and ep.getNumber() both returning null and get ture on that statement

your existing code

```
if ((p.getNumber() == null)&&(ep.getNumber()==null) )
```

is already doing that. Since you're getting an NPE on that line, `p` itself is `null`, or `ep` is `null`, or both. You should examine your `checkProduct()` and `checkexpensiveProduct()` methods, where `p` and `ep` are set, to see if they're working correctly.

Comment: i need to check that nulls and get true on that statement can i && those 2?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you rephrase?

Comment: i need to check p.getNumber() and ep.getNumber() both returning null and get ture on that statement

Comment: I edited. In your program, does it ever make sense for `p` or `ep` to be `null`? Or would they only ever be `null` if something went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

check your p variable and ep variable .One of them is null.check
 why

```
 dao.checkProduct(pnumber)
```

or

`dao.checkexpensiveProduct(pnumber);` is returning null

Answer (score 0):

What line is giving the `NullPointerException`? Be sure that `p` or `ep` are not null.

Comment: i need to check those are returning null and get ture and do else part.

Comment: If one of the objects is null, you can't use his methods like you did in your code. Check the methods `dao.checkProduct()` and `dao.checkexpensiveProduct()` to be sure that they will not return a null object. Instead, they can return a instatiated object without any attribute.

Comment: so you are saying if both return null its gonabe NullPointerException?

Comment: If one method return null, the code will throw the NullPointerException because you are trying to acess a method within a null object. When you do `p.getNumber()`, if `p` is null, you'll get a NullPointerException. Same thing for the `pe` object.